# How I can send login success and join game packets in Minecraft Server?

Tags: java, kotlin, protocols, minecraft, ktor

I have this situation:
I complete encryption and I have UUID and profile name and Game Profile (correct)
I attempt to send after `serverbound encryption response packet` - `clientbound login success packet` with this format:

```
override fun write(output: Output, packet: ClientboundLoginSuccessPacket) {
    output.writeUUID(packet.uuid)
    output.writeString(packet.username)
}
```

(uuid is sending 2 longs, and username is sending varint and byte array)
Change protocol state to PLAY
After this I send `clientbound play join game packet`
with this format:

```
output.writeInt(packet.entityId)
output.writeBoolean(packet.hardcore)
output.writeByte(packet.gameMode)
output.writeByte(packet.gameMode)
output.writeVarInt(1)
output.writeString("minecraft:world")

output.writeNBT(packet.dimensionCodec)
output.writeNBT(packet.dimension)

output.writeString(packet.worldName)
output.writeLong(packet.hashedSeed)
output.writeVarInt(packet.maxPlayers)
output.writeVarInt(packet.viewDistance)
output.writeBoolean(packet.debugInfo)
output.writeBoolean(packet.respawnScreen)
output.writeBoolean(packet.debug)
output.writeBoolean(packet.flat)
```

But when client receive this packet it get decoder exception: out of bounds exception
Why?

Answer (score 0):

You are writing the gamemode as a normal **Byte**, however the Minecraf client expects it to be an **Unsigned Byte**.

The difference between the two is that **Unsigned Byte** doesn't have a sign (+/-). Therefore, it takes less memory and is practically a completely different data type.

In Kotlin **Unsigned Byte** is represented by `UByte` class. You can write it to `Output` using `.writeUByte()` extension function.

Comment: writeByte() and writeUByte() haven't different
writeUByte code:
```@ExperimentalUnsignedTypes
public inline fun Output.writeUByte(v: UByte) {
    writeByte(v.toByte())
}
```
and code with it didn't fix my problem (index out of bounds exception)

Comment: @Cororo Can you provide a byte representation of an example packet created by your code?